# Destroyed my LifeRay+CAS installation

Tags: authentication, liferay

I'm using LifeRay in version 6.1 in combination with CAS. For testing purposes, I wanted to deactivate CAS temporarily and use the native login functionality of LifeRay instead. Therefore, I deactivated CAS in the Portal Settings. Now, I cannot login myself in LifeRay, because even if I click on "sign in" I got "You do not have permission to view this page." Where can I activate CAS again in the config-files or database OR how can I return to the native login functionality of LifeRay? Thank you!

Comment: Which version of Liferay. I am not sure why are you getting permission error, but based on your version, I can give you a workaround to login and change back the settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following in your portal-ext.properties(You can also create property hook, but since this is temporary, i would recommend you to change this for the moment do the clean up and then remove the property) and restart the server

```
auto.login.hooks=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.CASAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.FacebookAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.NtlmAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.OpenIdAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.OpenSSOAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.RememberMeAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.SiteMinderAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.ParameterAutoLogin
```

Once server is restarted add the following parameters to any of liferay's url

```
?parameterAutoLoginLogin=test@liferay.com&parameterAutoLoginPassword=test
```

Change credentials to your admin credentials

Comment: Thank you very much, I can use it again ;-)